# RivetsJS not updating after reassigning model

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I've been playing around with RivetsJS, and it works perfectly UNTIL I reassign the object that I originally used as the model. For example, I've been trying the following in JSFiddle:

**JavaScript:**

```
var testObject = {
    prop1: "ONE",
    prop2: "TWO"
};

var testObject2 = {
    prop1: "THREE",
    prop2: "FOUR"
}

var testBind = rivets.bind($("#properties"), {
    test: testObject
});

$("#randomize").click(function(e) {
    testObject.prop1 = Math.random();
    testObject.prop2 = Math.random();
});

$("#change").click(function(e) {
    testObject = $.extend(true, {}, testObject2);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="properties">
    <p>Prop1: { test.prop1 }</p>
    <p>Prop2: { test.prop2 }</p>
</div>

<button id="randomize">Randomize</button>
<button id="change">Change</button>
```

This works perfectly at first. The webpage shows "ONE" and "TWO", and when I click randomize, they show randomized values. When I click Change, however, nothing happens, and the elements stop updating when I click randomize.

I thought to try unbinding and binding again when Change is clicked, but that doesn't work either.

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9hFk/)

Answer (score 1):

They have a dedicated function for that, you can refer to the github discussion for this issue
https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/issues/131

you can now simply write this

`var otherTestObject = {
    test2: {
        prop1: "THREE",
        prop2: "FOUR"
    }
};
testBind.update(otherTestObject);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I think it keeps track of the object using the object reference, so when you reassign the full object, it stops working.

This Filddle  works because we are not reassigning the parent object.
http://jsfiddle.net/a9hFk/2/

```
var testObject = {
    test2: {
        prop1: "ONE",
        prop2: "TWO"
    }
};

var testObject2 = {
    prop1: "THREE",
    prop2: "FOUR"
}

var testBind = rivets.bind( $("#properties"), {
    test: testObject
});

$("#randomize").click(function(e) {
    testObject.test2.prop1 = Math.random();
    testObject.test2.prop2 = Math.random();
});

$("#change").click(function(e) {
    testObject.test2 = $.extend(true, {}, testObject2);
});
```